# uploading and playing the video in different pages(html5)

Tags: html

can we upload a video from our system in one html page using upload button and play the choosen file in other html page.

First page ---upload a video 
redirect to page 2 and play the video there  in html5

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but do remember that the video need to be available in `.mp4, .ogv` and `.webm` formats for the cross browser compatibility.

Comment: yes i have a .mp4 format video. can u give me an idea how we can do that.

Comment: Either you can upload the video in all the three formats else you need to convert it. Try free video converters present online.

Comment: so unless we have all the threes formats of the video we cannot do that?

Comment: can you tell me how to do that (if i have all the three formats) thanks in advance

Comment: No the video will still play but not in all the browsers. The browser supporting the video format will play the video else video will not be played.

Comment: but there aren't any resources/ Methods stating that we can upload and play the video's in 2 different html pages..

Comment: i know the compatibility  of html5 in different browsers. My question is not with compatibilty. Can we upload the mp4 video from local machine in page 1 (html) and redirect to page 2 and then play the video there. Thanks in advance

Comment: yes that can be done using document.location.href="your URL";

Comment: Do this after the upload is complete. You can link to the uploaded video in your page 2 from the location to which it is uploaded. The location can be passed in the page url.

Comment: can any one post an example of this kind or help me with the entire code... I am very very new to passing things as a paramerters.. Thanks in advance